# Unpack a list with many dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a problem with a list containing many dataframes. I create them in that way:

`listWithDf = []`

`listWithDf.append(file)`

And I got:

[image]

And now I wanna work with data inside this list but I want to have one dataframe with all the data. I know this is a very ugly way and this must be changed every time the quantity of the dataframe is changed.

`df = pd.concat([listWithDf[0], listWithDf[1], ...)`

So, I was wondering is any better way to unpack a list like that. Or maybe is a different way to make some dataframe in a loop, which contains the data that I need.

Comment: `pd.concat(listWithDf)`?

Comment: It works!!!! I didn't expect it to be that easy. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it as suggested in comments by @sjw:

```
df = pd.concat(listWithDf)
```

Here's a method with a loop(but it's unnecessary!):

```
df = pd.concat([i for i in listWithDf])
```